# Notification Bell Color Change in Salesforce Lightning after Spring'18

Tags: lightning-experience, task-notifications

After Spring'18 release the the notification bell color is changed to gray from red and this is causing issue for Sales Reps to notice this. 
We have Themes and Branding with Spring'18 but could not find if we can change the bell color back to red or any deep color.
Tried with Customized theme as well but the theme changes the header and not the bell icon or cody image color. 
We need to change the bell color. Any quick help will be much appreciated.

[image]

~Thanks.

Comment: can you post a picture for better understanding

Comment: Picture provided. As mentioned themes are not resolving the issue - fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this article stating it's on purpose in order for it to work with the new themes and branding feature.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269419&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: As there is an article stating it's on purpose I have created an idea on ideaexchange: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKcHQAU

Comment: We had to submit a case with the Salesforce support and now we have the red background back again.

Comment: I'll give this a go

Comment: I have found that with most of the standard themes the colour is now red, it  is just custom themes that still have this issue. Support confirmed they cannot change it from their end so I am guessing they made this change back for the standard themes for everyone.

Comment: It appears depending on the colours you set in your custom theme will assign a different colour automatically because if I use white in a custom theme it will still be red, I also tried a green colour for the sake and it was a dark navy colour. Just sucks for my theme that I get light grey on black.